# Android Studio SharedPreference Saving Login to Database

Tags: android, android-studio, save, sharedpreferences, mobile-application

I want to save the the user's login details when they first login the mobile application into my Device table and have them bypass the login screen every time the application opens.

I think I've got that part going it's just saving the variables I'm not understanding. My question is how and where should I begin saving the user's detail?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // declaring variebles
        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        etIpAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIpAddress);
        final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String ipAddress = etIpAddress.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
        if (sharedPreferences.contains("ip")) {
            performLogin(username, password, sharedPreferences.getString("ip", ipAddress));
        }

        // setting up things for login button
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String ipAddress = etIpAddress.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);

        String username = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("ip", ipAddress);
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putString("password", password);
        editor.commit();

        performLogin(username, password, ipAddress);
    }
});
        }
```

Comment: You are already doing same. getting any issue with current code?

Comment: It's saying invalid credentials cause isn't the variables currently saving nulls? Other than that, we're still checking whether the user's detail are in database before logging on rather than registering first time users and having them save their data into the database.

Comment: You should check the value in shared preferences before setContentView() and if it is there then start your desired activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
performLogin(username, password, sharedPreferences.getString("ip", ipAddress));
```

user getting login fail because both `username` and `password` is passing empty value to `performLogin` every-time when starting Activity.

In same way as getting `ip` also get `username` and `password` from `SharedPreferences` like:

```
if (sharedPreferences.contains("ip")) {
      String strUsername=sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
      String strPassword=sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
      String strIpAddress=sharedPreferences.getString("ip", ipAddress);
      performLogin(strUsername, strPassword,strIpAddress);
  }
```

Comment: Yep this worked thanks! However, I'm still having the issue of saving first time users.

Comment: So what's happening now is the application is allowing only registered users to get access, i.e. user's username and password are already in the database. I want to make it where first time users who access the application will have their details saved to the mobile application, i.e. register users in login screen.

Comment: @Lotse: for first time users you need to  register instead of login to user right? so i think there is no relation between non-register or register users

Comment: @Lotse: then what is problem im not getting your point. it's very good if u make a new question for next problem with full expiation

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the username and password from the shared preferences as like the ipAddress and then call the perfomLogin method.

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
 if (sharedPreferences.contains("ip")) {
            performLogin(sharedPreferences.getString("username", ""), sharedPreferences.getString("password", ""), sharedPreferences.getString("ip", ""));
    }`

Comment: Yep this worked thanks! However, I'm still having the issue of saving first time users.

Comment: @Lotse What the issue you are facing?

Comment: So I want to register first time users cause right now the application is checking if the user is registered within the database before performing login. I want first time users to be able to login and have their details save into the database.